# Why does Déjà Dup say there is no space left?

Tags: backup, disk-usage, deja-dup

I'm trying to backup my home directory (excluding a few folders). The backup is saved on a ~300 GB partition (called backups) of an internal drive, but not the same drive as the home directory. When I try to backup, everything goes OK until at some point Déjà Dup says there is no space left on "backups". The problem is that Déjà Dup only used ~20 GB at this point, so there is a ton of space left. I tried several times without luck.

Why is Déjà Dup saying this?

The size of my home directory, without the excluded folders, is 136 GB.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So there are three possible places where Deja Dup might be out of space, and I don't think its error message tells you which.  There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/872233) filed about that.

- You may have run out of space on the target partition (which it sounds like you didn't)
- You may have run out of space in your home directory (~/.cache/deja-dup can get large)
- You may have run out of space in /tmp

Comment: Strange that it explicitly says that "backups" is out of space although the problem it's in another partition.

I'll try to free some space in my home directory and in /tmp.

Thanks

Comment: In my case the message is `No space left in '/.'`  (one partition, which is 14% used) while the problem arguably comes from `~/cache/deja-dup` (another partition, almost 100% used). This is my own evidence that the error message is misleading as to where the problem actually resides

Answer (score 5):

You can move the location of the cache-directory as follows (create a symlink to a new cache location)

```
mkdir /othervolume/.deja-dup-cache
mv ~/.cache/deja-dup/* /othervolume/.deja-dup-cache/
rmdir ~/.cache/deja-dup
ln -sf /othervolume/.deja-dup-cache ~/.cache/deja-dup
```

to change the location of the tmp-directory have a look at the following post: [Deja Dup backup, change use of /tmp to another folder/location](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191653/deja-dup-backup-change-use-of-tmp-to-another-folder-location/284124#284124)

Comment: Hi, this is something I'd like to do as my .cache directory keeps filling up.  Will moving my deja-dup-cache to the same volume I'm backing up pose a security risk to an encrypted backup. My Home is encrypted but my backup volume is not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

I had >900Gb left on the partition,
13Gb left on the cache folder in ~
and /tmp contained only 13 Kb

I solved the problem just by rebooting

Answer (score 0):

I am operating my root system on an SSD drive, and once read an article about swapping certain folders like `/tmp`, `/var/log`, and so on to RAM, which lowers your potential RAM space and the size of the `/tmp` folder. Exactly this swapping of my `/tmp` folder caused the `no space left` error in Deja Dup.

[Here](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/SSD/Auslagerung) is what I did to my `fstab` back then (sorry, it's in German).

...and parts of the code to put in `fstab`:

```
tmpfs   /tmp    tmpfs   nosuid  0   0
```

So if you made the same changes to your fstab in order to improve performance, simply undo it like this:

```
# tmpfs /tmp    tmpfs   nosuid  0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try formatting your backup partition as **NTFS**.

I had exactly the same error when these two conditions came together:

- the backup partition is formatted as **FAT**.
- the backup included huge files such as virtual hard disc images for VirtualBox.

Formatting the backup partition as NTFS resolved the problem in my case.