# Deja Dup backup, change use of /tmp to another folder/location

Tags: backup, deja-dup

As the title suggests, I'd like to force Deja Dup to use a folder other than /tmp.

My backups fail due to size size restrictions, see bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1033552

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still sitting without a backup solution. Any help that solves the question will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backup no longer working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/216259/backup-no-longer-working)

Answer (score 2):

The above solution works, but is generally not a really good option if you just want to change the tmp-Folder of the deja-dup process!
Also I wouldn't sacrifice tmpfs because of this issue.

Since deja-dup uses duplicity as its backend to make the actual backup, the problem has to be solved for duplicity.
Duplicity uses the environmental variable TMPDIR which normally points to /tmp

To change the location of the TMPDIR for duplicity (deja-dup), simply open the terminal and run:

```
TMPDIR=/othervolume/otherfolder
export TMPDIR
deja-dup-preferences
```

Answer (score 0):

1.disable tmpfs:

`sed -i "s/^\(RAMTMP\=\).*/\1no/" /etc/default/rcS`

2.reboot

3.make a new temp dir in the partition that have more space. eg I will use the home dir
 with the appropriate permissions for read and write, and made a symbolic link to /tmp

`mkdir /home/tmp`
`chmod ugo+rw /home/tmp`
`ln -s /home/tmp /tmp`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I DO NOT want to stop using tmpfs, rather I want to change the location that deja dup uses.

I get a major performance boost using tmpfs and don't want to sacrifice that just to use deja dup.

Comment: Not everybody puts /home into a different partition, mainly because it becomes a partitioning pain if you wrongly guessed the amount of space you will need. Can you modify this advice for people like me who like to let all the files compete for the space they need?